# Pepper robot datetime rtc is out. thus cannot sync apps from app store (SSL auth failed)

Tags: gentoo, pepper

In a nutshell the sync for Pepper is not running between Pepper and Aldebaran. It gives an error that it cannot connect to server, please reboot.

Once rebooted the same error exists. So I debugged that screen on the web version accessed on Peppers IP and the actual error is SSL Authentication failed

I started an SSH session to get system time using timedatectl and got a result of 2014

I posed the question to aldebaran / softbank and they mentioned the rtc battery is likely depleted.

I cannot update the datetime using timedatectl as I dont have root access. Please advise if there is a way around time and date updates?

Kind regards,

Comment: Isn't it a NTP daemon running in Pepper ? and so connecting the robot to the internet will setup the clock ?

Comment: I also think the NTP deamon should snyc the time automatically. But therefore the ntp server needs to be accessible for Pepper. Our Pepper in a corporate network behind a proxy server once couldnt. Therefore i had to explicitly allow connections from Pepper to the NTP Server.
So you could also check if your Pepper can access the ntp server at all.
The NTP Server might be 0.gentoo.pool.ntp.org.

Comment: Try to connect Pepper to a mobile hotspot, then no firewall should prevent connecting to the ntp server. If the date on pepper is correct with that connection you know your other connection needs to be adapted.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and could fix the systemtime temporarily. 
This helps to work with Pepper while it is running.
But if the battery is empty the system time will be reset to 2014 after reboot nevertheless.
So this needs to be done after each reboot or in the long run Pepper needs to be exchanged for battery replacement.

Although you dont have root access, it is possible for you to modifiy the date via `timedatectl` command.

1. deactivate NTP `timedatectl set-ntp 0`
2. Enter root password: `root`
3. set time e.g: `timedatectl set-time "2018-11-20 11:26:45"`

Now you should be able to connect to aldebaran and sync Pepper.
To sync the time with ntp again you could:

1. activate ntp: `timedatectl set-ntp 1`
2. sync time with ntp server (e.g: 0.de.pool.ntp.org) `ntpdate -s 0.de.pool.ntp.org`

Comment: You might also want to contact the support team at Softbank Robotics see if they can fix this battery!