# How to install pip for installing external packages in NAO robot

Tags: python-2.7, pip, pygame, boto3, nao-robot

I have written some code and want to run it on NAO robot, but unfortunately the I used some packages like pygame and boto3 in my code, so now to work this code on NAO I have to install the packages on NAO robot, Can someone please explain the process, please.

I have tried running get-pip.py file on NAO using ssh nao@ip, but it can't install
I have been attempting copying the packages files to NAO, but it also doesn't solve the problem.
I followed the https://community.ald.softbankrobotics.com/ja/node/1506 forum, but it also doesn't solve it

Below is the console output when I run get-pip.py file

`PS C:\Users\hp> ssh nao@169.254.252.60                                                                                  Password:                                                                                                               nao [0] ~ $ su                                                                                                          Password:                                                                                                               root@nao [0] nao # ls                                                                                                   Ashim                              DigiCertHighAssuranceEVRootCA.pem  classes.bin  diagnosis  naoqi       recordings    DigiCertHighAssuranceEVRootCA.crt  angles.bin                         couples.bin  expo.bin   rayons.bin  remotes       root@nao [0] nao # cd Ashim                                                                                             root@nao [0] Ashim # ls                                                                                                 boto3     client_secret.json  example.py  jmespath   pip     python-engineio  six                                       botocore  custom-env          get-pip.py  mpolly.py  pygame  python-socketio  urllib3                                   root@nao [0] Ashim # python get-pip.py`

`DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.                            Collecting pip                                                                                                          /tmp/tmpdQ8F7J/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connection.py:324: SystemTimeWarning: System time is way off (before 2017-06-30). This will probably lead to SSL verification errors                                                                 /tmp/tmpdQ8F7J/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:354: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Server Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings                /tmp/tmpdQ8F7J/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:150: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings                                                                                          WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:504: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version'),)': /simple/pip/                                                                                                              /tmp/tmpdQ8F7J/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connection.py:324: SystemTimeWarning: System time is way off (before 2017-06-30). This will probably lead to SSL verification errors                                                                 /tmp/tmpdQ8F7J/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:150: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:504: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version'),)': /simple/pip/
/tmp/tmpdQ8F7J/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connection.py:324: SystemTimeWarning: System time is way off (before 2017-06-30). This will probably lead to SSL verification errors
/tmp/tmpdQ8F7J/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:150: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:504: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version'),)': /simple/pip/
/tmp/tmpdQ8F7J/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connection.py:324: SystemTimeWarning: System time is way off (before 2017-06-30). This will probably lead to SSL verification errors
/tmp/tmpdQ8F7J/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:150: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:504: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version'),)': /simple/pip/
/tmp/tmpdQ8F7J/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connection.py:324: SystemTimeWarning: System time is way off (before 2017-06-30). This will probably lead to SSL verification errors
/tmp/tmpdQ8F7J/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:150: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:504: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version'),)': /simple/pip/
/tmp/tmpdQ8F7J/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connection.py:324: SystemTimeWarning: System time is way off (before 2017-06-30). This will probably lead to SSL verification errors
/tmp/tmpdQ8F7J/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:150: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:504: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version'),)) - skipping
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pip
root@nao [err 1] Ashim #`

Also, I tried to update the system time, but this also not solves the problem. the output remains the same as before:

```
root@nao [err 127] nao # ntpdate                                                                                        
17 Sep 02:55:02 ntpdate[8986]: no servers can be used, exiting
root@nao [err 1] nao # ntpdate -s 0.de.pool.ntp.org
root@nao [0] nao # ntpdate
11 Jul 10:51:42 ntpdate[9024]: no servers can be used, exiting
root@nao [err 1] nao # cd Ashim
```

I also tried to install the packages without pip, using `sudo python setup.py install`
But in this case it shows the error below:

```
error: could not create '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli-1.16.196-py2.7.egg': No space left on device
```

Comment: isnt pip already installed on nao? I suppose it might work similar to pepper: check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48387823/install-things-on-pepper

Comment: what happes if you run get-pip.py?

Comment: it doesn't install the pip instead it shows error like this `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pip  `

Comment: @TVK I don't think there is a Naoqi 2.5 for NAO robots

Comment: please add the whole console output to your question. Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: I have pasted the whole console output in questioning when I run get-pip.py file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pip error - could not find a version that satisfies the requirement junos-eznc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43127536/pip-error-could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-junos-eznc)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+SystemTimeWarning%3A+System+time+is+way+off

Comment: It's not the duplicate question; it's totally different mate @phd

Comment: It's an exact duplicate.

Comment: I agree, now that we have more details.
Whats the output of "df -h"

Comment: What is "df -h"?

Comment: "df" (disk free) and "du" (disk usage) are commands that give information about your filesystem. This might help: https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-linux-no-space-left-on-device-error/

Answer (score 1):

You have a:

> SystemTimeWarning: System time is way off (before 2017-06-30). This
>   will probably lead to SSL verification errors

Fix your systemtime otherwise ssl verfication will fail.

It might work similar to pepper, follow the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53902765/pepper-robot-datetime-rtc-is-out-thus-cannot-sync-apps-from-app-store-ssl-auth)

You also get the

> SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Server
>   Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform.
>   This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate,
>   which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer
>   version of Python to solve this. For more information, see
>   https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings

To fix it you would need to install `requests[security]` package

You can also install packages witout pip as discribed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270877/how-to-manually-install-a-pypi-module-without-pip-easy-install)

Comment: I have changed my NAO robot's time using NTP but still getting the same response. 
`root@nao [err 127] nao # ntpdate                                                                                        17 Sep 02:55:02 ntpdate[8986]: no servers can be used, exiting
root@nao [err 1] nao # ntpdate -s 0.de.pool.ntp.org
root@nao [0] nao # ntpdate
11 Jul 10:51:42 ntpdate[9024]: no servers can be used, exiting`

Comment: please get used to updateing your question with what you have tried and the output. Still getting SystemTimeWarning?

Comment: I have tried installing packages without pip, but it shows: No space left  on device